# How are PHP attributes different from doc block annotations?

Tags: php, annotations, php-attributes

Lately, the [attributes RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/attributes_v2) has passed the voting stage. How they are different from DocBlock annotations, and what benefits will they bring?

Consider simple Doctrine entity, before:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entity {
    // …
}
```

After, using native PHP attributes:

```
#[ORM\Entity]
class Entity {
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The explanation at this part of the RFC: [Why not extending Doc Comments?](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/attributes_v2#why_not_extending_doc_comments) explains a lot of the benefits

- Namespacing prevents conflicts between different libraries using the same doc comment tag
- Checking for attribute existence is a O(1) hash key test compared to unpredictable `strstr()` performance or even parsing the docblock.
- Mapping attributes to classes ensures the attributes are correctly typed, reducing a major source of bugs in reliance on docblocks at runtime.
- There is visible demand for something like annotations based on its common use in so many different tools and communities. However, this will always be a confusing thing for newcomers to see in comments. In addition, the difference between `/*` and `/**` is still a very subtle source of bugs.

A lot of these boil down to the fact that attributes can be checked by PHP. Tools can leverage the fact that these attributes are already-parsed metadata visible with reflection, rather than comments that need to be parsed with a custom syntax per tool. IDEs and static analysis tools will be able to guarantee correctness without having to know a specific tool's docblock annotation syntax because the attributes resolve to classes that have to exist and might have further type annotations to add checking.

So:

- tools that define attributes that they use will benefit from correctness and performances gains because PHP will handle the parsing of these attributes for them
- tools that analyze PHP will benefit from the easier type-checking guarantees and standards for checking attributes' correctness
- humans will benefit from these tools' improvements and the fact that documentation and metadata can be better separated

Comment: Yeah, resoning in the RFC and use cases are quite extensive.

Comment: I ask so other people don’t have to.